# Asp.net MVC 3 stored procedure to return one value from the table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the SQL for what I want to return:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [Zinc].[GetUserByEmail]
    @Email nvarchar (256)
  AS
    SELECT zu.UserId FROM zinc.users zu WHERE zu.Email = @Email
```

Then in my repository I have so far:

```
public int GetUserByEmail(string email)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ZincModelContainer.CONNECTIONSTRING))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();

            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "[Zinc].[GetUserByEmail]";

            //not sure how to go from here?
        }
        return userId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a scalar value, use:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = email;
var UserId = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: @MajorByte - Thanks for your edit, and the addition to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = email;

int UserId = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Would the downvoter please leave a comment. Thanks, it's the decent thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Documentation is usually the best place to start.  Please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a.aspx for an example of reading from an SqlConnection.